# Programmatically spawn view after core data item add

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working on a SwitUI app that shows a list of items that I want to create/edit/delete. I've been working with Core Data, so I have a @FetchRequest in the view that retrieves the objects. Then a '+' button which creates a new object using the Core Data context, with a placeholder title, and adds it to the list. The user can then tap to edit an object in the list to add information to it using the editor view.

My question is, is there a way to programmatically open the editor view when a new object is created, passing in that same object?

I'm probably missing something simple, but I'm struggling to achieve this. I can't create the editor view in the parent view hierarchy, and show it by toggling a @State variable, as I don't have the newly created object at the time the View is instantiated.

Here's a bit of pseudocode to help illustrate more clearly:

```
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Object.title, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default) private var objects: FetchedResults<Object>

    @State var objectEditorIsActive: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {

        List {

          Button(action: {
               addObject()
            }, label: { Image(systemName: "plus") })

          // List of existing objects, with a button to open ObjectEditor
          // and pass in the corresponding object for editing.

          NavigationLink(
               destination: ObjectEditor(object: existingObject),
               isActive: $objectEditorIsActive,
               label: { ObjectView() })

        }


    }

    func addObject() {
        withAnimation {
            let newObject = Object(context: viewContext)
            newObject.title = "New Object"
            try? viewContext.save()
            // if this is successful, open ObjectEditor with newObject passed in.
            // Via NavigationLink ideally, but in a sheet or any other method is fine.
        }
    }
```

So basically I want to open ObjectEditor and pass in newObject in one button press, rather than requiring the user to have to specifically select the newly created object every time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is `ObjectEditor` code? What do you meant by *open*, in sheet?

Comment: @Asperi ObjectEditor can open in any way that works, but the app uses NavigationView, so I ideally want to open it via a NavigationLink. Added a bit more to the code to make that clearer.

Comment: This may help: https://augmentedcode.io/2020/01/19/using-coredata-with-swiftui/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach - the idea is to use dynamic binding to state property of newly created object and activate hidden navigation link programmatically.

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
@State private var newObject: Object?
private var isNewObject: Binding<Bool> {
    Binding(get: { self.newObject != nil },  // activate when state is set
    set: { _ in self.newObject = nil })      // reset back
}

...

List {

  Button(action: {
       addObject()
    }, label: { Image(systemName: "plus") })

  // List of existing objects, with a button to open ObjectEditor
  // and pass in the corresponding object for editing.

}
.background(
  NavigationLink(     
       destination: ObjectEditor(object: newObject),
       isActive: isNewObject,       // << activated programmatically !!
       label: { EmptyView() })
)

...

func addObject() {
    withAnimation {
        let newObject = Object(context: viewContext)
        newObject.title = "New Object"

        if let _ = try? viewContext.save() {
          self.newObject = newObject          // << here !!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is definitely a useful approach I hadn't considered. The main issue now is newObject is optional. The passed object has an @ObservedObject wrapper in the editor view, so I'm unable (as far as I know) to make it optional. But I think I should be able to create a struct to bridge the CoreData object and the view itself, to provide something for the editor to draw State from, that then writes the data to the real object.